# ¿Con qué puedo realizar una comparación de formas en Android Java?

Tags: java, android

Quiero realizar un proyecto donde necesito tomar una fotografía de alguna figura compleja, por ejemplo, la silueta de una botella para después asignarle un valor, digamos: 1. La fotografía sería guardada en el dispositivo para después ser comparada con la cámara, es decir, al apuntar a la misma botella, la aplicación retorne como valor: 1.

¿Existe alguna herramienta que pueda usar para lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

a eso se le llama "Computer Vision", y eso se debe hacer con librerias externas , existen muchas librerias para eso como OpenCV , o la libreria de google que es de pago llamada "ML KIT"

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas herramientas para eso. La mayoría son server-side pero [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/android) es gratis porque es on-device. Es decir, que funciona offline. Google tambien tiene la [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels)
 que esa sí es de pago pero igualmente tiene una free qouta. El ML Kit for Firebase, ahora llamado [Firebase ML](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/label-images) es una combinación de las 2 y por eso las funciones que usan la Cloud Vision API tienen un costo. Pero todo lo que sea on-device es gratuito.